# VueJs get value input radio in request axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

Hello i have this object

```js
values: {
            false: 'order expected',
            true: 'order cancel'
        }
```

I'm loop this object inside radio button i wan't to get the value (true or false) in radio button to add in my request axios i'm do that

```html
<div
                    v-for="(index, type) in values"
                    :key="type.id"
                    class="filters__filter-items__type"
                  >
                    <radio-button
                      v-model="order"
                      checked-color="black"
                      class="filters__filter-items__type__radio"
                      :value="index"
                      :name="type"
                      :label="type"
                    />
                  </div>

<button @click="applyFilters"> send </button>
```

```js
export default {
 data() {
  return {
    order:''
   }
 },
 methods: {
async applyFilters() {
      const app = { $axios: this.$axios };
      const results = await endPoint.searchOrder(
        app,
        this.order
      );
      return results;
    },
  }
}
```

when i do that my request params is `&params=order expected` not `&params=false`
I don't understand why please help me thanks

Comment: Thats not an array, it is an object. And you can't use v-for for objects.

Comment: @Daniel That's not true. `v-for` *can* be used with objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [iterating an object with `v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object), the first argument is the `value`, and the second is the `key`:

```html
<div v-for="(index, type) in values">
             value key
```

You're currently binding the object value (i.e., `order canceled`, etc.) to the radio button's value, but the binding should actually use the object key (i.e., `false`).

A quick fix is to swap the `index` variable for `type` in the `v-for`:

```html
<!-- BEFORE -->
<div v-for="(index, type) in values">

<!-- AFTER -->
<div v-for="(type, index) in values">
```

...or in your bindings:

```html
<!-- BEFORE -->
<radio-button v-model="order"
              :value="index"
              :name="type"
              :label="type"
              />

<!-- AFTER -->
<radio-button v-model="order"
              :value="type"
              :name="index"
              :label="index"
              />
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-iterate-obj-with-vfor?file=src/components/RadioInput.vue)